# ajax rendering from redmine view hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-plugins

I new in rails.
I trying to write redmine plugin to extend sidebar with chat. Hook works with static data. How to pass data? generated by controller?

I have simple controller and list.js.erb

```
$('#chat-plugin-messages').empty().append("<ul> <%= j render @messages %> </ul>");
```

How to call it from hook?

hook

```
module ChatPlugin
  class Hooks < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
     render_on :view_projects_show_sidebar_bottom,
              :partial => 'hooks/chat/sidebar'
  end
end
```

upd:

View has been rendered, but controller not called. So i have `nil` in `@messages` variable.

UPD:

Code
https://github.com/alex-eri/redmine-chat

This works with  now, but i want render same block with .

Comment: what exactly does not work? And post what hook do you use?

Comment: @gotva :view_projects_show_sidebar_bottom

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can look at this [code](https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_tracker_accessible/blob/57b74d98f9a2baa569f061fb4aa1335d3b1ac799/lib/redmine_tracker_accessible/hooks.rb) (hook `view_issues_form_details_top`) and implement the similar logic in your app

Comment: i tried like this `context[:controller].send(:render, { :partial => 'hooks/chat/sidebar', :locals => {:messages => @messages} })`, but @messages in view is nil.

Comment: не передается переменная во вьюху...
и мне говорили, если рендер вызываешь, то рельсы вызовут соответствующий контроллер (не вызывают) или я контролленр для partial неправильно обзываю...

Comment: Your phrase confuses me a lot: `View has been rendered, but controller not called`. Lets clearify: you add `before_filter` to some action where you define veariale `@messages` then you are trying to display it through hook somewhere on sidebar. Is it correct?

Comment: after django rails confuses me totally. what before_filter?
i ecxept according my web searches if i write <%= render 'chat/list' %> rails call controller, then renders view, but nope. then i copy-paste code from controller to hook. in hook i defined @messages, but it does not passed to chat/list view.